# SwiftUI NavigationLink opened with swipe

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have NavigationLink with destination and isActive. Documentation says:

```
init(destination: Destination, isActive: Binding<Bool>, label: () -> Label)
Creates an instance that presents destination when active.
```

And it works when label is pressed, but when I try to swipe over label it opens destination regardless of value of isActive. Note that on click is not invoked when swiping.
Is this desired behaviour or it is some bug in SwitUI? Should I set some flag to turn this off?

Edit:
Example

```
 @State var isActive = false
 var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello"), isActive: $isActive) {
            Text("Open something if isActive is true")
        }
```

Comment: How/where are you using the `NavigationLink`? You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. I would suspect the issue isn't with `NavigationLink` itself but with the context where you use it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I added example, but it is pretty much basic use case. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Any visible NavigationLink is triggered by user interaction (if not disabled explicitly). Variants of constructors just give *additional* ability to manage link programmatically.

Comment: @Asperi, thanks, this answers my question. I did not understand this from documentation (I am not sure if it is explicitly written anywhere :D ), and that caused my confusion.